# mysqli::$error contains no error message if I move its access too far away in return chain

Tags: php, mysqli

As per the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php I expect an empty string to be indicative of there being no error. All my classes are using a database object that gets passed around each and retrieved by this class method `getConn`:

```php
public function getConn() {
    return $this->_conn;
}
```

And the database class contains exactly:

```php
public function __construct() {
    $this->_conn = new mysqli(self::$host, self::$user, self::$password, self::$schema);
    $this->_conn->set_charset(self::$charset);
    ...
}
...
```

The destructor indicates that it is the last thing to destruct and this is where the connection is forcibly closed.

My API is invoked in a way which results in this class method executing in `file1.php` which in turn calls `create` on `$this->_p`:

```php
class PAPI {
    public function __construct(APPDB $DB) {
        $this->DB = $DB->getConn();
        $this->_p = new APPP($DB);
        ...
    }
    ...
    private function _newC() {
        ...
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; $i ++) {
            if ($_FILES['p']['size'][$i] > 0) { /// files not guaranteed to be present
                if (($res = $this->_p->create($_FILES['p']['tmp_name'][$i], $cid, $uid)) !== APPP_STATUS::APPP_SUCCESS) {
                    switch ($res) {
                        ...
                        case APPP_STATUS::APPP_SQLERR:
                            APPCore::Log(json_encode($this->DB->error));
                            return new PAPIError(PAPI_ERROR::PAPISQLERR, PAPI_ERROR_MSG[PAPI_ERROR::PAPISQLERR], $this->DB->error);
                        ...
                    }
                } else {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`create` is seen here in the second class in `file2.php`, it calls `setP` on `$this->_c`:

```php
class APPP {
    public function __construct(APPDB $DB) {
        $this->DB = $DB->getConn();
        $this->_c = new APPC($DB);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function create(string $tmp = null, int $cid = null, int $uid = null, string $table = null) {
        ...
        if ($this->_c->setP($cid, $hash, $table) === APPC_STATUS::APPC_SUCCESS) {
            ...
        } else {
            APPCore::Log(json_encode($this->DB->error));
            return APPP_STATUS::APPP_SQLERR;
        }
    }
}
```

And `setP` is seen here finally in `file3.php`:

```php
class APPC {
    public function __construct(APPDB $DB) {
        $this->DB = $DB->getConn();
    }
    ...
    public function setP(int $id = null, string $hash = null, string $table = null) {
        ...
        $target = self::_tableFromHash($table);

        $params = [
            json_encode([$hash]),
            $id
        ];

        $updateCQuery = $this->DB->prepare("UPDATE `${target}` SET `p` = ? WHERE id = ?");

        /*!< since table is an argument, this could fail if the table doesn't exist */
        if ($updateCQuery === false)
            return APPC_STATUS::APPC_SQLERR; /*!< this is where it the error propagates out from */
        ...
    }
}
```

It is expected that `APPC_STATUS::APPC_SQLERR` should be returned from the final line included in the snippet - **this occurs** and it is seen by `file2.php`. In `file2.php` the `APPCore::Log(json_encode($this->DB->error));` succeeds if it is left uncommented, and the error makes it out to the log. Note that this has crossed execution over one return from another file. If I instead `return APPP_STATUS::APPP_SQLERR;` in `file2.php` and log from the switch in `file1.php` instead of the successful position that would otherwise be left in `file2.php`, then the value of `$this->DB->error` is an empty string.

Why is it empty when the only path the execution has taken, is a return into a switch statement? I have verified that only one instance of the database class exists and the a server disconnection is only made much after the empty `mysqli::$error` is observed. I.e., I cannot find anywhere where the the `mysqli` object performs any tasks between returning, and accessing its error property.

I have **verified** with mysql's general_log, that the last query is indeed the last query and that a quit is made *very* shortly after.

```
2020-09-14T06:36:06.025182Z        10 Prepare   INSERT INTO `p` (`code`, `uid`, `cid`, `private`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())
2020-09-14T06:36:06.025222Z        10 Execute   INSERT INTO `p` (`code`, `uid`, `cid`, `private`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES('c288b073d41f26753a937d02056a14864ae1959d', NULL, 22353, NULL, NOW(), NOW())
2020-09-14T06:36:06.029293Z        10 Close stmt
2020-09-14T06:36:06.030761Z        10 Quit
```

I thought it worth pointing out that although referring to the `mysqli::$error` property doesn't *consume* it, that I am shifting the reference to it from `file2.php` to `file1.php` where it makes more sense in the surrounding software.

What is happening and how do I prevent it happening such that I can access the error appropriately?

Debugging shows the following sequence:

1. [image: Before the error arises]
2. [image: Once the error arises]
3. [image: Step Once Return]
4. [image: Step Once Return]

The differences between each of these images are two steps 1 to 2, call `$this->DB->prepare(...);` and return because of the error and each of the other steps are single steps (F11 in VSCode with XDebug server).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: @Progman it's not exactly possible as I don't know what's causing it and wasn't able to develope an MRE for it outside of the code I included which I had to heavily redact.

Comment: Based on the code you have you remove all the code which is not relevant to the problem as long as it shows the error. When it isn't possible to remove any other code lines you will have a MCVE to share. Without the MCVE it would be a lot of guessing what might happen where in code we don't even see. Please [edit] your question to include the MCVE.

Comment: The answer is that the statement goes out of scope so the error is lost at some stage when access it made to it outside of the original scope.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your actual problem: there is no magic. Either there is a new connection is created somewhere, or there is another successful query is called, thus nullifying the error message.

Either way, that's a minor issue compared to that outdated method of checking errors you are using. It's 2020 now and time to use exceptions. Seriously, **90% of this code will just disappear in a puff of smoke**.

Just [tell mysqli to throw exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting). Now, you can start writing your code straight away, **without a single `if` statement** intended for the error checking.

Let me to recreate the full elaborate code for a single query execution:

```
$updateCQuery = $this->DB->prepare("UPDATE `${target}` SET `p` = ? WHERE id = ?");
if ($updateCQuery === false)
    return APPC_STATUS::APPC_SQLERR;
}
$updateBind = $updateCQuery->bind_param("ss", $hash, $id);
if ($updateBind === false)
    return APPC_STATUS::APPC_SQLERR;
}
$updateExecute = $updateCQuery->execute();
if ($updateExecute === false)
    return APPC_STATUS::APPC_SQLERR;
}
```

and compare this monster of a code with the following code snippet:

```
$updateCQuery = $this->DB->prepare("UPDATE `${target}` SET `p` = ? WHERE id = ?");
$updateCQuery->bind_param("ss", $hash, $id);
$updateCQuery->execute();
```

Moreover, the same goes for all the levels above. There is no need for the elaborate error checking in the other files either

```
    if ($this->_c->setP($cid, $hash, $table) === APPC_STATUS::APPC_SUCCESS) {
        ...
    } else {
        APPCore::Log(json_encode($this->DB->error));
        return APPP_STATUS::APPP_SQLERR;
    }
```

will become just

```
$this->_c->setP($cid, $hash, $table);
```

and

```
            if (($res = $this->_p->create($_FILES['p']['tmp_name'][$i], $cid, $uid)) !== APPP_STATUS::APPP_SUCCESS) {
                switch ($res) {
                    ...
                    case APPP_STATUS::APPP_SQLERR:
                        APPCore::Log(json_encode($this->DB->error));
                        return new PAPIError(PAPI_ERROR::PAPISQLERR, PAPI_ERROR_MSG[PAPI_ERROR::PAPISQLERR], $this->DB->error);
                    ...
                }
```

will become just

```
$res = $this->_p->create($_FILES['p']['tmp_name'][$i], $cid, $uid);
```

but surely you would like to know where to put that logging and returning code. And I have an answer for you: in the error/exception handler. Just create a **single** place where all errors being logged and the appropriate message is returned to the client. A simple exception handler would catch all errors that would ever occur, and handle them in a single place in the uniform manner, without the need of writing the elaborate error checking code on the every level.

Comment: I don't really appreciate you projecting your coding style upon me. How do you expect to receive error information if the server just returns a 500 or similar?
With regards to the actual problem. I have evidence that no other connection is established, and no other query executed. Is the quit to blame? Perhaps if it is to blame there's a mechanism to stop it quitting before the script ends since PHP is doing the quitting itself at the moment.

Comment: "How do you expect to receive error information" - that's what set_exception_handler() function is for.